# Factorize $f(X)=X^4+1$ on $L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $L= \mathbb{Q}[Y]/(Y^4+1)$. Factorize $f(X)=X^4+1$ on $L$.

My attempt: We know that $\alpha = \overline{X}=X+(X^4+1)$ is one of the root of $f(X)$ in $L$. Now using the relation $\alpha^4+1=0$ and using simple division method, we can factorize $X^4+1 = (X-\alpha)(X^3+\alpha X^2+\alpha^2 X+\alpha^3)$. Is this the final factorization? How do we know that there are not more roots in $L$?

Edit: I have changed the variables in the field $L$ from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Which factor is 0 here?

Comment: The function $f(X)$ is in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Here, $L$ is an extension field where we can find one of the root of $f(X)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie This question makes sense, in exactly the same way that it makes sense to factor $x^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$. The confusion is coming from the fact that OP  used $X$ to represent the variables in two different polynomial rings!

Comment: OP, I highly recommend using different variable names, for example $L = \mathbb{Q}[Y]/(Y^4+1)$ and $f(X) = X^4 + 1$, or something like that.

Comment: First, note that $-\alpha$ is also a root of $f$!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk the other two roots will be $\alpha^3$ anf $-\alpha^3$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk You are right. Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid confusion I will give a new name to the indeterminate:

> Factor $f(t)=t^4+1$ over $L$.

You already found the root $\alpha$ and hence the factor $t-\alpha$ of $f$ in $L$. But there are more! Notice that $f$ contains only even powers of $t$, so $-\alpha$ will also be a root. Now by division we get $f(t)=(t-\alpha)(t+\alpha)(t^2+\alpha^2)$. So we are reduced to factor $t^2+\alpha^2$. Notice that if there was an element $i\in L$ such that $i^2=-1$ we could write $t^2+\alpha^2=(t-i\alpha)(t+i\alpha)$. Can you find such an element?

Answer:

> Take $i=\alpha^2$.

Comment: Isn't $\alpha^3$ and $-\alpha^3$ along with $\alpha$  and $-\alpha$ are the 4 roots. This is what you are getting from your solution.

Comment: Yes, $\pm\alpha,\pm\alpha^3$ will be the four roots of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** consider the $\mathbb Q$-algebra map $f \colon \mathbb Q[X] \to \mathbb Q(\xi_8)$, $X \mapsto \xi_8$, where $\xi_8$ is an $8$-th primitive root of unity. Since $\xi_8^8 = 1$, we have $(\xi_8^4)^2 = 1$. But $\xi_8^4\neq 1$, as $\xi_8$ is primitive, so we necessarily obtain $\xi_8^4 = -1$ and thus $\xi_8$ vanishes at $x^4+1$.

On the other hand, a standard fact of cyclotomic polynomials is that

$$
\deg m(\xi_8,\mathbb Q) = \varphi(8) = 4,
$$

so $m(\xi_8,\mathbb Q) = X^4+1$. By construction, this is (a generator of) the kernel of $f$, hence

$$
\mathbb Q[X]/(X^4+1) \simeq \mathbb Q(\xi_8).
$$
Maybe the latter presentation can help you.

> The cyclotomic polynomial has as roots primitive roots of unity. These are characterized as powers of $\xi_8$ with exponent coprime with $8$; hence $T^4+1 = (T-\xi_8)(T-\xi_8^7)(T-\xi_8^3)(T-\xi_8^5)$.